# How to change the time of a pandas datetime object to the start of the hour?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a `pandas` `Dataframe` in which one of the column is pandas datetime column created using `pd.to_datetime()1`. I want to extract the date and hour from each datetime object, in other words, I want to change the minute and seconds to 0.

I used `normalize()` to change the time to midnight but don't how how to change the time to start of the hour. Please suggest a way to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

making some test data and turning it into a dataframe

```
rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2018 11:59:00', periods=3, freq='min')
df = pd.DataFrame(rng)
print(df)
print(df[0].round('H'))
```

gives the input

```
                    0
0 2018-01-01 11:59:00
1 2018-01-01 12:00:00
2 2018-01-01 12:01:00
```

and rounded to the nearest hour gives

```
                      0
0   2018-01-01 12:00:00
1   2018-01-01 12:00:00
2   2018-01-01 12:00:00
```

and

```
print(df[0].dt.floor('H'))
```

gives

```
                      0
0   2018-01-01 11:00:00
1   2018-01-01 12:00:00
2   2018-01-01 12:00:00
```

if you always want to round down.  Likewise, `ceil('H')` if you want to round up

Comment: I don't need to round though, I need 11:59 as 11:00 here. Is there any such function to do this?

Comment: `floor('H')` will do that for you!

Comment: Thanks buddy! @Paul Brennan

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to checkout `pandas.Series.dt.strftime`

Or try this:

```
import datetime
df=pd.DataFrame({'timestamp':[pd.Timestamp('today')]})
df['Date']=[pd.to_datetime(i.date())+ datetime.timedelta(hours=i.hour) for i in df['timestamp']]
```

Comment: I tried that. But then the value doesn't remain of the type pandas datetime I think?

Comment: Suhas Mucheria, we can also use .floor('H')